# Mysql Select Two Rows in One

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select in one row grouped by a same key other two values in the same field:

```
TABLE
attribute_id
entity_id
value

DATA
attribute_id|entity_id|     value
          85|      220|      4740
         257|      220|image1.png
```

And need this result:

`attibute_id 85` as SKU, `attribute_id` 257 as IMAGE in this result:

```
SKU  | IMAGE
4740 | image1.png
```

How can I do this? TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `attribute_id|entity_id` combinations unique across the table you don't need to group data, just join like this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b2f60/2

```
SELECT a.entity_id,
       a.value AS some_attribute1,
       b.value AS image
FROM attribs a
LEFT JOIN attribs b
ON a.entity_id = b.entity_id
   AND b.attribute_id = 257
WHERE a.attribute_id = 85
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
select ts.entity_id, ts.value as sku, ti.value as image
from t ts join
     t ti
     on ts.entity_id = ti.entity_id and
        ts.attribute_id = 85 and
        ti.attribute_id = 257;
```

You can also solve this using conditional aggregation:

```
select t.entity_id,
       max(case when t.attribute_id = 85 then t.value end) as sku,
       max(case when t.attribute_id = 257 then t.value end) as image
from t
group by t.entity_id;
```