# SQL - spliting one column to two separated (diffrent condition)

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I don't know how to split one column to two separated with diffrent condition.

If contact is type == 'E' would like save AS email, otherwise type == '6' save AS phone.

[image]

I need result like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your requirement , you already know (by type) which is which so why split into separate columns? And what does this mean anyway , are you talking on a select or a change to KONTAKTI?, please add your expected outcome as text..

Comment: Please post data and code as text not images. Provide the desired output as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql select two rows in one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434978/mysql-select-two-rows-in-one)

Answer (score 2):

You want CASE expression

```
select *, 
   case when type = 'E' then contact end email,
   case when type = '6' then contact end phone
from KONTAKTI
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add those columns to the table there are two options to achieve this.

First create a copy of kontakti with the desired changes.
Please note that I had to assume your datatypes.

```
create table kontakti_temp (
    ac_subject varchar(8),
    type char(1),
    phone varchar(16),
    email varchar(256)
);
```

Then insert the data from kontakti into kontakti_temp and split the contact fields by using case.

```
insert into kontakti_temp
select ac_subject
      , type
      , case when type = '6' then contact end as phone
      , case when type = 'E' then contact end as mail
from kontakti;
```

Then rename both tables accordingly

Or you could use a create table as statement

```
create table kontakti_temp as
select ac_subject
      , type
      , case when type = '6' then contact end as phone
      , case when type = 'E' then contact end as mail
from kontakti;
```

The datatypes of the columns in kontakti_temp will be derived from the ones returned by the above select statement.

Answer (score 1):

Select:

```
select ac_subject,
   max(case when type = '6' then contact end) phone,
   max(case when type = 'E' then contact end) email
from kontakti
group by ac_subject
;
```

Test DDL:

```
create table kontakti (
    ac_subject varchar(8),
    type char(1),
    contact varchar(256)
);
  
INSERT INTO kontakti
    (`ac_subject`, `type`, `contact`)
VALUES
    ('a1', 'E', 'email@gmai.com'),
    ('a1', '6', '41895478'),
    ('b2', 'E', 'aa@emai.si'),
    ('v5', '6', '243243'),
    ('v5', 'E', 'me@email.si')
;

create table kontakti_temp as
select ac_subject,
   max(case when type = 'E' then contact end) email,
   max(case when type = '6' then contact end) phone
from kontakti
group by ac_subject
;
```

Output:

| `ac_subject` | phone | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `a1` | 41895478 | email@gmai.com |
| `b2` | `(null)` | aa@emai.si |
| `v5` | 243243 | me@email.si |